# @font-face not working when adding www. prefix to address

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm working on a website with a font I uploaded. It works fine in all browsers but in Firefox and IE, when I add www. to the url in the browser, the font doesn't show up? Does anyone know what's up?

This is my CSS declaration:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ITCAvantGardeGothicProDemi';
src: url('../fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.svg#') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what website? might help

Comment: `http://www.yoursite.com/css/fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.eot`, do not forget `http://`

Comment: where on the website is the `@font-face` supposed to apply?

Comment: did you try to use: `/css/fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.eot` instead? like `url('/css/fonts/itcavantgardepro-demi-webfont.eot');
`